# Vuejs script setup cannot contain ES module exports

Tags: vue.js

Following the setup guide for Vuejs and Pinia

```html
<script setup>
import {useStore} from "../stores/store.js";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    return {
      store,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I get the following error from Vite:

```sh
[vite] Internal server error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] <script setup> cannot contain ES module exports. If you are using a previous version of <script setup>, please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227.
```

How do I move to a version of `<script setup>` that will allow me to do the above?

Thanks!

Comment: `<script setup>` is `setup()`, rtm: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Comment: This defies the purpose of script setup, which is to remove boilerplate code. It's unlikely that the guide suggests that, more likely there was <script>, not <script setup>.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A bit of confusion on my end it seems. The docs talk about adding `<script setup>` and then also demonstrate using `setup(){}`, but they don't explicitly state that its one or the other.

Method 1:

```html
<script setup>
import {useStore} from "../stores/store.js";

const store = useStore();

// do stuff
</script>
```

Method 2:

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import {useStore} from "../stores/store.js";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    // do stuff

    return {
      store,
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mismatched two methods of local components registration.

Check:

- https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration
- https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#what-is-a-composable

When using SFC with , imported components are automatically registered locally:

```js
<script setup>
import { useStore } from '../store/store.js'

const { store } = useStore()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add Following code to your main.js file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

const app = createApp(App)


.use(createPinia())
app.mount('#app')
```